# Minecraft Plugin launchProjectiles Question

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft, bukkit

I wanted to code my own Weapon System with launchProjectile and im using an Arrow. But how can I increase the Arrow speed while don´t increasing the Spread. Heres the Code:

```
@Override
public void shootEffects(Player player) {
    Arrow projectile = player.launchProjectile(Arrow.class);
    projectile.setVelocity(projectile.getVelocity().multiply(1));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't very clear but I think what you want is a 100% accurate arrow travelling at high speed.

If so, this is for you :)

```
@Override
public void shootEffects(Player player) {
    Arrow projectile = player.launchProjectile(Arrow.class);
    projectile.setVelocity(e.getPlayer().getEyeLocation().getDirection().multiply(HIGH_NUMBER));
}
```

Here we are taking the direction the player is looking in, getting it as a vector and multiplying the vector to increase the speed.

Comment: thanks but it just spread very much. when i put 10 in the multiply and i shot with the weapon, it just spreads on the left or right side

Comment: Even with my code? If you see it spreading, it might be a visual glitch. Try hitting entities with it. :)

Comment: wow it works thank you! I gonna try to fix this visual glitch

Comment: do you have an Idea how i can fix the Glitch?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a client issue and can only be resolved by Mojang.